# The Morse Index of a $T$- periodic geodesics is a integer number?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, index-theory

It is well known that compact Riemannian manifolds $(M, g)$ with
periodic geodesic flows have ( Besse Book) exceptional spectral properties: the spectrum
of  $ \sqrt{ - \Delta}$, the square root of the Laplacian, concentrates along the arithmetic
progression [$(\frac{ 2 \pi}{T}$) $(k + \beta)$: $k=1, 2, ...$] with $T$ the (minimal) period of
the geodesic flow $G^{t}$ and with ; $\beta$ the common Morse index of the $T$-periodic
geodesics.

My question is: $\beta$ is a integer number if $T = \pi$, for example ?